Installing Tailwind in Laravel project using Vite and NPM
I'm unsure what command to put in the dev script in package.json so that npm run dev works correctly. I'm trying to use Tailwind with Laravel.
All I want is to install Tailwind in my Laravel project using Vite.
I'm not familiar with installing packages, so I'm still trying to decide what to try. If you answer the question, could you also let me know if there's anything else I need to install?

Is this for fresh project? Ongoing project? If fresh, I suggest you install laravel with breeze. It comes pre package with Tailwind and vite plus authorization/authentication feature (e.g login logout register etc)
